# IBM Application Center not list apps via Public URL

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I am using IBM Application Center version Version: 7.0.0.00-20150312-0731 which comes with MobileFirst Platform foundation consumer edition.

Its configured on WAS ND 8.5.5 in a clustered  environment and DB2 database.

If i access the App Center console via internal ip and port, it list the application published in the console.

The same is not listing if, i access the console via Public IP / DNS. Getting the error in console - "Server error. Contact the server administrator."

No logs printing on the ApplicationCenterCluster log file for the same request. 
But for local ip access i can see all the logs printing.

No clue were is the problem.

[Trace and SystemOut log files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dgt44861hzv6g2d/TraceLogs_Archive.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Try running the server with trace enabled. Maybe the trace.log will have more information. It sounds though like a routing error on the network level? `<logging traceSpecification="com.ibm.puremeap.*=all:com.ibm.worklight.*=all:com.worklight‌​.*=all"/>`

Comment: It seems like the request to not going to the ApplicationCenter services application from WebServer. Do we need to add the Host Alias for internal ip DNS also in default host and update the same in Plugin_cfg.xml of IHS. I enabled the Trace, but no log printing while i access the epicenter console via public DNS.

Comment: Updated the question with Trace and Systemout log files.

Comment: The error HMGR0024W that appears in the log states comes from Websphere when it tries to access web02.sng.int.sl.metlife.com but cannot determine the IP address of that server. No nameserver that Websphere can access seems to know that name. It is also not ping-able...

Comment: Updating the /etc/hosts with those names and ip. Restarting the servers. Will post you.

Answer (score 1):

1) As it seems you use IHS in front of WAS you must configure the proxy endpoints as documented here : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/r_ac_appres_endpoint.html

2) In ApplicationCenterClusterMem02 you have an error HMGR0024W meaning that the WAS high availability manager was unable to resolve the IP address for DNS Name. Either the host is unknown or has mappings to duplicate IP addresses.

Comment: Hi Bruno. Thanks.  I updated the /etc/hosts file for the IP address to resolve the name.  Not sure what to set for ibm.appcenter.services.endpoint, can i set my load balance DNS and port and protocol.

Comment: Yes. For the ibm.appcenter.services.endpoint property you need to set your load balancer protocol/hostname/port and the admin services context root. So the value must be : <protocol>://<load balancer host>:<load balancer port>/<admin service context root>

Comment: configured the same and restarted the cluster. But now getting the "Timeout exceeded" error in the console.

Comment: The timeout probably occurs when the console invokes the admin service with the value of the ibm.appcenter.services.endpoint property. You have to check if the load balancer correctly redirects the request to one of the WAS node. For that surely the best way is to set a debug trace on the load balancer.

Comment: My load balance is pointing to only WEB01 and WEB02 public IP's. Not the WAS server. LoadBalance --> WEB01/WEB02 --> WAS01 / WAS02 cluster.  WAS servers has only private network. All the servers are able to access via internal ip from one another.

Comment: You must check that the LoadBalancer is able to accept requests coming from the WAS servers since the console invokes REST services thru the LB and then the Web servers. Other point to check : the virtual host mapped to the console and admin service web modules must authorize the Web Server port (80 by default and 443 if you use https)

Comment: I have similar cluster and load balance environment for another project on WorkLight Consumer Edition 6.1.0.2. Not if these additional configuration were done. It was working on plain installation. Not sure why all these new configurations for MobileFirst Application Center version 7.0

Comment: Hi Bruno, IBM PMR L3 Support helped to resolve this issue. As i have a Clustered topology and both my WAS01 and WAS02 servers in a private LAN, its not able to ping the  AppCenter admin services. So we created JVM process definition custom property entries in both Cluster Members with the internal IP / URL. Then its started working fine. This procedure is no were documented in Info Center. Thanks Again.